# Provide types to const middlewares for express-zod-api

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, zod

I have a NodeJS server, where I use `express-zod-api` to validate inputs and responses. We chain middlewares, using something like this:

```
const workingExample = defaultEndpointsFactory.addMiddleware(createMiddleware({
    input: z.object({}),
    middleware: async () => {
        return {
            id: "an id",
        }
    }
})).addMiddleware(createMiddleware({
    input: z.object({}),
    middleware: async ({options}) => {
        console.log(`this is typed as a string: ${options.id}`)
        return {
            ...options,
            something: "else",
        }
    },
}))
```

However, I want to use the middlewares like lego - I don't always want the same middleware in the same order, so I have extracted them separate constants:

```
const middlewareA = createMiddleware({
    input: z.object({}),
    middleware: async () => {
        return {
            id: "an id",
        }
    },
})

const middlewareB = createMiddleware({
    input: z.object({}),
    middleware: async ({ options }) => {
        console.log(`this fails because option is "unknown": ${options.id}`)
        return {
            ...options, // TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.
            something: "else",
        }
    },
})

const brokenExample = defaultEndpointsFactory
    .addMiddleware(middlewareA)
    .addMiddleware(middlewareB)
```

This gives me TS errors because the `options` object is `unknown`. In the working example, where middlewares are directly chained, I suppose TypeScript can figure out what `options` is supposed to be.

I think I need to provide additional information to TypeScript, e.g.:

```
const middlewareB: MiddlewareDefinition<any, any, any, any> = createMiddleware({
```

I could painstakingly figure out what the `any`'s should be, but it will make everything pretty inflexible, especially if I am mixing and matching middlewares. Is it possible to genericise `middlewareA` and `middlewareB` to just... do the right thing and let TS figure it out?

Sample repro: https://github.com/crummy/express-zod-middleware

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to finagle a nice-ish resolution to the problem.

```
const middlewareA = async () => {
        return {
            id: "an id",
        }
    }

const middlewareB =  async ({ options }: { options: {  id: string } }) => {
        return {
            ...options,
            something: "else",
        }
    }

const brokenExampleFixed = defaultEndpointsFactory
    .addMiddleware(createMiddleware({
        input: z.object({}),
        middleware: middlewareA
    }))
    .addMiddleware(createMiddleware({
        input: z.object({}),
        middleware: middlewareB,
    }))
```

Using this method, I can share the middlewares, with only the mild additional effort of explicitly typing the parts of the input they need, and Zod + TypeScript handles all the rest.